# Overriding RaisePropertyChanged to execute additional code

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, inotifypropertychanged

In my model i have properties which i want to execute some extra code for when the property gets changed. I want to add the new value and the property name to my database. I also want to keep a list of current alarms (value is equal to true).

```
    public Boolean ActionAlarmLowLow
    {
        get
        {
            return _ActionAlarmLowLow;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._ActionAlarmLowLow)
            {
                Boolean oldValue = _ActionAlarmLowLow;
                _ActionAlarmLowLow = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ActionAlarmLowLow", oldValue, value, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i do this properly?
I am wondering if i should add two lines of code to the property:

```
DB.Log.addLogItem("ActionAlarmLowLow", value);
AlarmList.UpdateItem("ActionAlarmLowLow", value);
```

Or if i can somehow extend/override the RaisePropertyChanged and do some extra stuff elsewhere for specific properties. I.e calling something called

```
RaisePropertyChangedWriteToDbUpdateAlarmList();`
```

Comment: what is preventing you from firing your own event right after the RaisePropertyChanged one? Just place another call to your own event there, and handle the DB call in there... or, maybe this is what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246108/how-can-i-raisepropertychanged-on-property-change

Comment: It looks like you already know the answer. If it's a single property, just add those lines in its setter. If you need this for multiple properties, then create a helper method that logs, updates and calls `RaisePropertyChanged`.

Comment: It is multiple properties that require this functionality. Having one or two extra lines of code on each seems like extra work. That is why im asking how to implement a custom RaisePropertyChangedWriteToDbUpdateAlarmList();`which can to both. I think Jegan have answered about the mechanics..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is quite simple, all you need is to create a base class with INotifyPropertyChanged and call whatever you want inside.

```
public abstract class NotifyPropertyChangedBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
        var propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
        {
            // Do your common actions here, before property change notification is fired
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            // Do your common actions here, after property change notification is fired
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public Boolean ActionAlarmLowLow
    {
       get
       {
           return _ActionAlarmLowLow;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value != this._ActionAlarmLowLow)
           {
               _ActionAlarmLowLow = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(() => this.ActionAlarmLowLow);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering. Do you think i can combine this with the MVVM light  "ViewModelBase" which I already have implemented? 
public abstract class NotifyPropertyChangedBase: ViewModelBase instead of INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: To combine with MVVM Light, have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461278/mvvm-light-toolkit-how-to-use-propertychangedmessage